# Simple img gallery crossfading effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, gallery

I am learning a javascript a bit and wanted to make a webpage with image gallery on the top of the page. This is result I have so far: https://streamable.com/v636mv
I am loading images from the server via PHP, and showing them with javascript function.

But it looks like that some blib occurs every second time and I dont know how to fix it.
I hope that CSS and html should be fine, so most probably the issue is with the javascript itself ?
I ended up with the setInterval function which is calling my crossfadeFunction in 5s interval.

(I wanted to make something simple, without using any libraries, simply because I wouldnt understand them, I am affraid).

Anyway here is the link for the code: https://pastebin.com/Bj1P2vuR

for the javascript:

```
    function preloadImages() {
    for (let i = 0; i < imgNamesArray.length; i++) {
        const image = new Image();
        image.src = `./images/${imgNamesArray[i]}`;
        image.onload = () => {
            // You can optionally do something when each image is preloaded
        };
    }
}

fetch("gallery.php")
.then(Response => Response.json())
.then(fetchedData => {
    // tuto nieco rob s imgNamesmi ?
    imgNamesArray = fetchedData;
    console.log(imgNamesArray);
    //const currentImage = document.getElementById('currentImage');
    //currentImage.src = `./images/${imgNamesArray[0]}`;
    // displayNextImage();

    preloadImages();

    const initialIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgNamesArray.length);
    const initialImageSrc = `./images/${imgNamesArray[initialIndex]}`;
    currentImage.src = initialImageSrc;  

    /* setInterval(() => {
        // displayNextImage();
        crossfade();
    }, 5000); */

    setInterval(crossfadeII, 5000);

})
.catch(error => console.error("Error: ", error));


function displayNextImage() {
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % imgNamesArray.length;
    console.log(currentIndex);
    const currentImage = document.getElementById("currentImage");
    currentImage.src = `./images/${imgNamesArray[currentIndex]}`;
}



function crossfadeII() {

    let newIndex; 

    do {
        newIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgNamesArray.length);
    } while (newIndex === previousIndex || newIndex === currentIndex);

    previousIndex = currentIndex;
    currentIndex = newIndex;

    // Preload the next image

    const preloadIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % imgNamesArray.length;
    const preloadImage = new Image();

    preloadImage.src = `./images/${imgNamesArray[preloadIndex]}`;
    currentImage.src = `./images/${imgNamesArray[currentIndex]}`;

    console.log(`previousIndex: ${previousIndex}, currentIndex: ${currentIndex}, newIndex: ${newIndex}, match: ${previousIndex === currentIndex ? "matched" : newIndex}`);

   // currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % imgNamesArray.length;

    if (currentImage.classList.contains("current")) {
        currentImage.classList.remove("current");
        currentImage.classList.add("next");
    } else {
        currentImage.classList.remove("next");
        currentImage.classList.add("current");
    }

    if (nextImage.classList.contains("next")) {
        nextImage.classList.remove("next");
        nextImage.classList.add("current");

        nextImage.src = `./images/${imgNamesArray[previousIndex]}`;
        // preloadImages();
    } else {
        // console.log("lets imagine");
        nextImage.classList.remove("current");
        nextImage.classList.add("next");
    }
}
```

many thanks

Comment: Any idea ? anyone ?

Comment: ok it looks that this is a dead thread. :/